# CGridView css manipulation

Tags: php, css, yii, cgridview

In my CGridView the table generated by the grid method is using a default css class named .grid-view.  Is it possible to change the class name?  In my page, I am using two grid views and the theme of the grid view is different, one in a green color and the other in red.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look of this documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView

You can change the class of your `filterCssClass`, `loadingCssClass`, `itemsCssClass`, etc.
Just add the specific attribute to your widget.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(),
    'loadingCssClass'=>'loading-class',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'item-class'
));
```

Comment: You link didn't provide answer how to change `.grid-view`. I have read that.

Comment: @aslingga i had read that, can you provide which part that can change class name `.grid-view` ?